# Multi series surface graph / area graph

Tags: r, plot, time-series, surface

I am trying to come up with a way of displaying my data, which looks like this.

```
Day    Signal    Week
1      -0.01     1
2       0.03     1
3       0.01     1
4      -0.001    1
5       0.09     1
1      -0.10     2
2      -0.012    2
3       0.05     2
4       0.07     2
5      -0.01     2
```

The data represents return data from Monday to Friday for a given week. What I want to show in the most fancy way is how stable the signal behaves over time. The axis have to be like this plot that I created

[image]

So I want to have my x-axis to represent the days, the y-axis the signal and the z axis the weeks. So each week should be visible as a slice. Ideally I would have sth like this [Image](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/hypersphere_surface/hypersphere_surface.html). I tried inputting the data as a matrix into plot_ly which didn't work. I am fairly new to R so any help would be appreciated

[EDIT]
That's what I tried so far where mat is the data from above in one matrix with 3 columns

scatterplot3d(mat$x,mat$y,mat$z,main="lovely graph")

plot_ly(mat, type = "surface")

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you mean when you say that you tried inputting the data as a matrix in plot_ly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  It assumes that you're original data is a data.frame called `df`.

```
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)

df1 <- dcast(df,Day~Week,value.var="Signal")
mat <- as.matrix(df1[,-1])

plot_ly(z=mat, type="surface")
```

If you want to change the axis labels you can do the following:

```
plot_ly(z=mat, type="surface") %>% 
  layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "Week"),
                      yaxis = list(title = "Day")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that looks good, one more questions, could you add how you can set the axis labels and axis tick sizes or limits please?